# Using out in a recursive function in C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a method that sums and outputs it using `out`. My method looks like this:

```
public void MyMethod(int page, string city, out int citySum)
{
    citySum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        citySum++;
    }

    if(page < 15)
    {
       MyMethod(page + 1, city,out citySum); 
    }
}
```

What confuses me is I want to out `citySum` as total. But with this configuration, `citySum` becomes zero at each recursive step. How can I hold the value of `citySum` and pass it to the next recursive step?

Comment: why `for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {citySum++;}` and not `citySum += 50;`?

Comment: Stop using out param and return that integer instead of void from your method.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski I need to use out param, it's a requirement.

Comment: You don't use `city` parameter at all…

Comment: @DmitryBychenko This is a simplified version of my original method, I can't post the actual code here.

Comment: We can only answer the question you asked, not the question you *should've* asked. If the example code isn't representative of your real code then you're only going to get answers related to the code here, whether they can be applied to your real code is unknown.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I think what I want to achieve in the code is pretty clear in the question. Both methods have the same core functionality. And I got the desired answer.

Comment: Personally I'd just return the result instead, but it sounds like you actually want to use `ref`.  Otherwise you'd need to use one parameter as an input and another as the output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By simply introducing a new variable to hold the result temporarily

```
public void MyMethod(int page, string city, out int citySum)
{
    citySum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        citySum++;
    }

    if(page < 15)
    {
        int tempSum = 0;
        MyMethod(page + 1, city, out tempSum); 
        citySum += tempSum;
    }
}
```

---

Or using `ref` instead

```
public static void MyMethod(int page, string city, ref int citySum)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        citySum++;
    }

    if(page < 15)
    {
        MyMethod(page + 1, city, ref citySum); 
    }
}
```

[Working example on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/qq2Ly3)

---

Or returning the result directly:

```
public static int MyMethod(int page, string city)
{
    int citySum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        citySum++;
    }

    if(page < 15)
    {
        citySum += MyMethod(page + 1, city); 
    }

    return citySum;
}
```

[Working example on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/VcRCS1)

Comment: Don't know how I missed your version of returning the result directly when I wrote my answer! Shouldn't tie myself into the OP's code as much. Also this version 3 is the best answer.

Comment: One question : Wouldn't citySum be zero when I call it  in the next recursive step?

Comment: Thanks by the way for the answer

Comment: @jason You're welcome. The `citySum` of the next recursive call will be the `tempSum` of the previous so there won't be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use out and return the int from the method. Also use `+= 50` makes the code cleaner.

```
public int MyMethod(int page, string city, int citySum = 0)
{
    //for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    //{
    //  citySum++;
    //}

    citySum += 50;

    if (page < 15)
    {
        return MyMethod(page + 1, city, citySum);
    }

    return citySum;
}
```

Note that here `citySum` is set to `0` by default but can be set by the calling method. To workaround this you could use a `public` method that exposes this one by changing it to be `private`:

```
public int MyMethod(int page, string city)
{
    return MyMethod(page, city, 0);
}

private int MyMethod(int page, string city, int citySum)
{
    //...
```